# How to calculate max values of groups?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like so (I'm not sure how to format tables)

```
Category / Products / Purchases

1 | A | 12

1 | B | 13

1 | C | 11

2 | A | 1

2 | B | 2

2 | C | 3
```

Expected output:

```
1 | B | 13

2 | C | 3
```

However I keep on getting

```
1 | A | 13

2 | A | 3
```

ie. It just selects the first occurrence of the second column. 
Here is my code:

```
SELECT Category, Products, MAX(Purchases) FROM myTable GROUP BY Category;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use filtering in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.purchases = (select max(t2.purchases) from t t2 where t2.category = t.category);
```

Answer (score 1):

With NOT EXISTS:

```
select m.* from myTable m
where not exists (
  select 1 from myTable
  where category = m.category and purchases > m.purchases
)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hcsBdLynNS3yfyY9tnTF6P/0).
Results:

```
| Category | Products | Purchases |
| -------- | -------- | --------- |
| 1        | B        | 13        |
| 2        | C        | 3         |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use row_number() to identify max purchase for each group or replace rownumber() to rank() if there are ties of max  purchases for each group

```
     Select   Category, Products, 
          Purchases from (Select Category, 
            Products, 
          Purchases, 
        row_number() over (partition by 
      category, products order by 
         purchases desc) rn from table) t 
       where t.rn=1

       )
```